# Any way to Call A Function As A String?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I've just started a project, and am wondering if you can call a function (in an event listener) through a string.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var threesec:Timer=new Timer(3000, 1);
var whaton:String="tsecc"
threesec.start();
threesec.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, whaton);
function tsecc(tsecc:TimerEvent):void{
    trace("Hello")
    threesec.reset();
    threesec.start();
}
```

This does not work because of this line:

```
threesec.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, whaton);
```

and this error code:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Function.
```

I know what I am doing is horribly wrong, but is there a correct way to call a function in string format?

Do I have to add a property to the variable, do I have to create another type of variable?

Comment: is there a correct way to call a function in string format? Or to call a function with a variable

Comment: I think what @WillTower was asking for was not the immediate problem you have but why you are trying to call the function in this convoluted way. Just use the real function name and be done with it. There's no point in doing it the way you want in the code you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
threesec.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, this[whaton]);
```

I used "bracket syntax" to do this. You can learn more about it by searching on the Internet.

Comment: I knew there was something like this, but I didnt know what it was. Thank you!